# Meaning of 'Thank you so freaking much'

Tags: meaning-in-context, euphemism

One of my friends received lots of beautiful gifts on her birthday and she thanked by saying this. So what is the difference between just saying' Thank you so much 'and 'Thank you so freaking much.'

Answer (score 4):

"Freaking" is a less obscene version of the curse "fucking", which is used to add emphasis. The word refers to intercourse, but is frequently used as either an exclamation (e.g. "Fuck!"), a curse (e.g. "Fuck you!"), or an emphatic stand-in for many other words, (e.g. "What the fuck was that?")

An equivalent phrase would be:

> Thank you so very much.

This is just a vernacular way of thanking someone emphatically. I would avoid saying "freaking" around anyone who is sensitive to vulgarities, even if it is less vulgar than "fucking".

Answer (score 1):

"Thank you so freaking much" is also a way to say "thank you so VERY much", but maybe only when speaking to friends or relatives.

"FREAKING" was used as an adjective to describe the extent to which your friend was grateful for her gifts.

I also do not recommend that you use it because, as the user above stated, it could come off as offensive or even sarcastic. It is often seen as a more acceptable vulgar word.